# Solr autocomplete based on edismax type error

Tags: autocomplete, solr, edismax

i receive the following error when trying to implement auto-complete based on edismax type.

```
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: field "locality_ng" was indexed without position data; cannot run PhraseQuery (term=львів)
at org.apache.lucene.search.PhraseQuery$PhraseWeight.scorer(PhraseQuery.java:241)
at org.apache.lucene.search.DisjunctionMaxQuery$DisjunctionMaxWeight.scorer(DisjunctionMaxQuery.java:145)
at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:317)
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:551)
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:324)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1275)
```

schema types:

```
        <fieldType name="text_suggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <!--charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/-->
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <!--charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/-->
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- autocomplete_edge : Will match from the left of the field, e.g. if the document field
         is "A brown fox" and the query is "A bro", it will match, but not "brown"
    -->
    <fieldType name="autocomplete_edge" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <!--charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/-->
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([\.,;:_])" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="50" minGramSize="2"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <!--charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/-->
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([\.,;:_])" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(.{50})(.*)?" replacement="$1" replace="all"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- autocomplete_ngram : Matches any word in the input field, with implicit right truncation.
         This means that the field "A brown fox" will be matched by query "bro".
         We use this to get partial matches, but these whould be boosted lower than exact and left-anchored
    -->
    <fieldType name="autocomplete_ngram" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <!--charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/-->
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="20" minGramSize="2"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <!--charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/-->
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(.{20})(.*)?" replacement="$1" replace="all"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

schema fields

```
        <!-- AutoComplete fields
         Construct documents containing these fields for all suggestions you like to provide
         Then use a dismax query to search on some fields, display some fields and boost others
     -->
    <field name="locality_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <!-- The main text to return as the suggestion. This is not searched -->
    <field name="locality_suggest" type="text_suggest" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" multiValued="true" />

    <!-- A variant of textsuggest which only matches from the very left edge -->
    <copyField source="locality_suggest" dest="locality_nge"/>
    <field name="locality_nge" type="autocomplete_edge" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />

    <!-- A variant of textsuggest which matches from the left edge of all terms (implicit truncation) -->
    <copyField source="locality_suggest" dest="locality_ng"/>
    <field name="locality_ng" type="autocomplete_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" />
```

solr config, use the following request handler with edismax type:

```
  <requestHandler class="solr.SearchHandler" name="autocomplete" >
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    <str name="rows">10</str>
    <str name="fl">*,score</str>
    <str name="qf">locality_suggest locality_ng^5.0 locality_nge^10.0</str>
    <str name="debugQuery">false</str>
</lst>
```

this error occurred only if query contains specific symbols like + - $ @ after word

львів+в
київ+а

any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
    <field name="locality_ng" type="autocomplete_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" />
```

into

```
    <field name="locality_ng" type="autocomplete_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" omitNorms="true" multiValued="true" />
```